# Physics Problem with Coulomb's Law and One Axis

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, electromagnetism

I have 3 point charges placed at the x-axis in the table below I will show their positions.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline\mathrm{q_1}&2\ \mathrm{\mu C}&x_1&0\ \mathrm{m}\\ \hline \mathrm{q_2} & -3\ \mathrm{\mu C}& x_2 & .40\ \mathrm{m}\\ \hline \mathrm{q_3} &-5\ \mathrm{\mu C} & x_3 & 1.20\ \mathrm{m} \\ \hline \end{array}

These points are reference points from the origin meaning its $.4$ meters from the origin and so on. My question is why is my summation wrong I calculate summation of forces acting on the second point charge, $q_2$.
This is how I did it:
\begin{equation}\hat{F}=k\frac{qq}{r^2}\hat{r} \end{equation}
I also used $k$, Coulomb's Constant, to be defined as $9.00\cdot 10^9 \mathrm{\frac{N\cdot m^2}{C^2}}$
So for my attempt I did the following:
\begin{align}\sum F&=F_{21}+F_{23}\\ &=(9.00\cdot10^9)(\frac{-3\cdot 10^{-6}\times 2\cdot 10^{-6}}{.4^2}+\frac{-5\cdot 10^{-6}\times -3\cdot10^{-6}}{.8^2}) \\ &=-0.127\ \mathrm{N} \end{align}
I have the Schaum's 3000 problem Physics Series and it says that the answer is $-.55\ \mathrm{N}$. Am I wrong?

## Edit

I would like to point out that my subscript notation was also wrong here, and here is the corrected one.
\begin{align}\sum F&=F_{12}+F_{32}\\ &=(9.00\cdot10^9)(\frac{-3\cdot 10^{-6}\times 2\cdot 10^{-6}}{.4^2}+\frac{-5\cdot 10^{-6}\times -3\cdot10^{-6}}{.8^2}) \\ &=-0.127\ \mathrm{N} \end{align}

Comment: The equation you have $(F=kq_iq_j/r^2)$ is for the magnitude of the forces, what about the direction of the forces?

Comment: @RyanK The forces are acting in a one dimensional plane so the signs of the forces matters which would be cosine of pi and cosine of 0 and so on (meaning -1, and 1)

Comment: It would appear you did not factor this into your solution.

Comment: @RyanK Thanks I typed up my own answer I realized that I missed a negative sign. I included a Free Body Diagram, and even the original problem set up enjoy.

Comment: Why does your table say "$\mathrm{nC}$" 
 (which presumably means nanocoulomb, $10^{-9}$, when your working and expected answer seem to assume $\mathrm{\mu C} $ (microcoulomb, $10^{-6}$)?

Comment: @Deepak Let me check I did this on my calculator

Comment: @Deepak Yes Its Micro

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky Yes, it has to be micro. Else it doesn't work.

Comment: @Deepak It was given in MircoCoulombs, that was a misprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Force Diagram]

After realizing my mistakes, and taking into account the repulsive force that Charge 2 experinces is the opposite direction of the positive x. So taking that into account I would need to add a negative sign in my solution to get the right solution to the problem.
\begin{align}\sum F&=F_{21}+F_{23}\\ &=(9.00\cdot10^9)(\frac{-3\cdot 10^{-6}\times 2\cdot 10^{-6}}{.4^2}+-\frac{-5\cdot 10^{-6}\times -3\cdot10^{-6}}{.8^2}) \\ &=-0.550\ \mathrm{N} \end{align}

## Edit

I would like to admit that the subscript notation is also wrong in this answer.
\begin{align}\sum F&=F_{12}+F_{32}\\ &=(9.00\cdot10^9)(\frac{-3\cdot 10^{-6}\times 2\cdot 10^{-6}}{.4^2}+-\frac{-5\cdot 10^{-6}\times -3\cdot10^{-6}}{.8^2}) \\ &=-0.550\ \mathrm{N} \end{align}